What's the best way to upload an ILP file into QuestDB? Extended
There was a question with the same title 1 year and 7 months ago, and this question is closed.
I used the script from the answer
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def send_utf8(msg):
    print(msg)
    sock.sendall(msg.encode())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sock.connect(('localhost', 9009))
        with open("YOUR_FILE") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                # print(line)
                send_utf8(line)
    except socket.error as e:
        sys.stderr.write(f'Got error: {e}')
    sock.close()

it works but after some seconds I got an error:
Got error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
I tried to slow down the script with a sleep(0.01), so I got a little more data into questDB but after some minutes there comes also the error again.
And I also tried something with "signal" I found on stack overflow, but I din't get it work for my whole file with 18GB.
Can somebody help me to extend the script for continuous work.

Broken pipe usually means the reader or writer stopped reading / writing. Are you sure you can just dump lines into the receiver? Do you need to read replies? Do you need to flush buffers?

You can use CURL
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:9000/write' --data-binary @data.txt

Or as a python script
import requests
url = 'http://localhost:9000/write'

# Open the data file and send it as binary
with open('data.txt', 'rb') as file_data:
    # Send a POST request
    response = requests.post(url, data=file_data)


Given the file is not huge it should be ok to upload in 1 go. If it is, it's better to split it into multiples but without breaking the ILP lines.
QuestDB is now compatible with InfluxDB for writing, it accepts HTTP hence compatible with CURL uploads.
